# Alias for vue route with parameter

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a user profile route like this `/user/Mary/profile` where I can see any users profile and I want to create an alias like `/me/profile` so that the user name parameter is hidden and use a constant instead for that parameter.

Something like:

```
const myUserName = 'Mike';

export default [
  {
    name: 'user',
    path: 'user/:username',
    alias: 'me',
    component: () => import('components/user-layout'),
    children: [
      {
        name: 'user-profile',
        path: 'profile',
        component: () => import('components/user-profile'),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I'm not sure if above is correct and how I should set the `username` parameter to the `myUserName` constant in case of user access `/me/profile`.

** I DON'T want to `username` param to be `myUserName` by default, it will be only in case of user access that route by the `/me` alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I ended up by creating another route for `/me` and didn't make alias or redirected, just a normal route with shared children between it and `/user`, like this:

```
import userChildrenRoutes from './user-children.routes';

export default [
  {
    name: 'me',
    path: 'me',
    component: () => import('components/user-layout'),
    children: userChildrenRoutes,
  },
  {
    name: 'user',
    path: 'user/:username',
    component: () => import('components/user-profile'),
    children: userChildrenRoutes,
  },
];
```

and in `beforeEnter` hook I can handle the username.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you can't use alias for dynamic routes. I' suggest you to simply create another root called `me` and redirect it to `/user/yourUserName`. I've prepared a [sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/1zwgt2rp/).

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
    { path: '/foo', name: 'foo', component: Foo },
        { path: '/user/:username', name: 'user', component: User, children: [
      {
        name: 'user-profile',
        path: 'profile',
        component: Profile,
      },
    ]},
        {path: '/me', redirect: `/user/${someWhereFromSessionUserName}`}
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @dganenco for your dedicated time on this answer, but it doesn't solve my problem because I need to keep showing the `/me` url for the user instead of redirecting it to `/user`

Comment: In this case you can try to use [navigation guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) and especially [beforeEach()](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) hook. I've updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/k0mvodju/) and please let me know if it works. It's a really good question.

Comment: thx, I've tried this before and didn't work, I couldn't see `/me` in browser address bar, I have managed it by creating another independent route as you can see in my answer